# Significance of p functions in compounds of the lighter alkaline and alkaline earth metals

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, alkali-metals, alkaline-earth-metals

It is often said that lithium follows the duet rule instead of the octet rule, unlike the more "usual" main-group elements.

My question is the following:

Does this hold for $\ce{Be, Na}$ and $\ce{Mg}$ as well?

Comment: Which sort of lithium compounds are you speaking of ? And which calculation ?

Comment: That's not true even for lithium - it's usually tetracoordinate.

Comment: So-called lithium duet compounds are not so.  An organolithium compound, for instance, is oligomeric.

Comment: Btw, what exactly is "p function"?